# How to set and get an object stored in Redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I'm trying to store an object in redis, and when I get the object it doesn't seem to work.

I tried:

```
u = User.new
u.name = 'blankman'

$redis.set('test', u)

x = $redis.get('test')

x.name  // error
```

I guess it is a serialization issue, do I have to do something special to my model for it to serialize?

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest using the `Marshal.dump` and `Marshal.load` to serialize and deserialize objects respectively.

```
$redis.set 'key', (Marshal.dump object) #serialize
object = Marshal.load($redis.get 'key') #deserialize
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, redis will save a String representation of your object. So...

```
x.class # String
```

You have to use something to serialize/deserialize your objects when using Redis. Take a look at https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects

Kind Regards