# Convert JSON back to ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So currently I have a Model class

```
class Book
  # author_id
end
```

I have a simple delegator class for the Model class above

```
class BookDecorator < SimpleDelegator
   attr_accessor :list_of_reviews
   
   def initialize
      super
      @list_of_reviews = []
   end
end
```

I tested it on Rails Console

```
-> book = Book.find(1)
-> book = BookDecorator(book)
-> book.list_of_reviews  
-> []
```

However when I serialize the object to JSON

```
-> book = book.to_json
-> Deserialize back
-> book = JSON.parse(book)
-> book.list_of_reviews
-> NoMethodError: undefined method `list_of_reviews` for <String:0x00007>
```

How do I deserialize the JSON back to ActiveRecord with the decorator attached?

The reason why I have to serialize to JSON because I have to store it in Redis.

And deserialize later to access that `list_of_reviews` method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set and get an object stored in Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053091/how-to-set-and-get-an-object-stored-in-redis)

Answer (score 4):

There is no automatic way of "deserializing" a record back from JSON. Its a one way process. A very naive solution would be:

```
book = Book.new(JSON.parse(book))
```

However the record will not behave like a record that has been persisted and fetched from the database which can cause issues.

There is also the issue that you're casting the attributes of a record to the primitive types supported by JSON. One example of this is that JSON does not have a proper decimal type which can cause rounding errors and that associations won't be serialized/deserialized.

This entire endavor seems very much like a wild goose chase as [Rails has tons of caching mechanisms already](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) to solve most problems.